# Getting "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" while trying to make connection to remote DB server using Java

Tags: oracle, jdbc

My code to test connection to database :-

```
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,
    ConnectException
    {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:oracle:thin:UNAME/PSWD@//
    hostname:1521/servicename");
    con.close();
    }
```

Error : -

```
    SQLState(08006) vendor code(17002)
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: 
    The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException
    (SQLStateMapping.java:100)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException
    (DatabaseError.java:144)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:258)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:482)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon
    (T4CConnection.java:488)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>
    (PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at 
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>
    (T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection
    (T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect
    (OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at webdriver.TlgDB.main(TlgDB.java:20)
    SQLState(99999) vendor code(17430)
    java.sql.SQLException: Must be logged on to server
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException
    (SQLStateMapping.java:71)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException
    (DatabaseError.java:144)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:258)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:266)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.createSqlException
    (DatabaseError.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.assertLoggedOn
    (T4CConnection.java:3828)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff
    (T4CConnection.java:569)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>
    (PhysicalConnection.java:662)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>
    (T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection
    (T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect
    (OracleDriver.java:528)at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
    (Unknown Source)at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
    (Unknown Source)at webdriver.TlgDB.main(TlgDB.java:20)
    getConnection failed: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 
    IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 
    IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon
    (T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>
    (PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>
    (T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection
    (T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect
    (OracleDriver.java:528)at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
    (Unknown Source)at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
    (Unknown Source)
    at webdriver.TlgDB.main(TlgDB.java:20)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could 
    not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute
    (ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute
    (AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection
    (NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:347)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
    ... 12 more
```

Tried below steps so far but no luck yet :-

1. wrong connect descriptor - but i am able to connect using this same TNS using TOAD for Oracle.

2.Must be logged on to server - i started toad and connected to the db but faced same issue.

3.`tnsping hostname` gives `'tnsping'` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

4. Firewall setting is off in control panel.
5. tried to use connection string as :-

   ```
   String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)        
   (HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))"+
   "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))";
   ```

and passing this `url` to `getConnection` obj but still faced same issue.

Any suggestion would be appreciated ?

Comment: Try getConnection all in one line. (Could be some hidden characters here)

Comment: Your URL is wrong for connecting to a service name, see the duplicate.

Comment: @Bjarte...my connection string is in one line only in the IDE like this :-                                     getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/servicename","uname","passwd");       in the above code that you see...its just because of stack overflow editing rules that you see white spaces

Comment: @MarkRotteveel...checked with that way also...but same error.                                             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:uname/pwd@//hostname:1521/servicename");

Comment: @MarkRotteveel...could you please suggest something else ?...the previous suggestion didn't work.